# Print css not being applied in ie11

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I built css for a webpage to look decent for printing. This css is working fine for Chrome, but for some reason none of the styles are being applied for internet exploder 11.

Is there some trick to allow these print styles to take effect? All I could find was that internet exploder will ignore filter css.

My css is this

```
@media print {
    .noPrint
    {
    display: none;
    }

    .noButtonSpacer {
        margin: .25em;
    }
    .tab-content > .tab-pane {
        display: block !important;
        opacity: 1 !important;
        visibility: visible !important;
    }

    button,
    .nav-item,
    .newCommentArea {
        display: none !important;
    }
    select,
    input,
    .form-control {
        //border: none;
        background-color: #fff;
        width: 100% !important;
    }

    label,
    span,
    p,
    input,
    body,
    html,
    .col-md-2,
    .row,
    .contaniner,
    .form-inline label {
        text-align: left !important;
        justify-content: left !important;
    }

    .container .col-md-2,
    .container .col-md-3,
    .container .col-md-4,
    .container .col-md-5,
    .container .col-md-6 {
        width: 50% !important;
    }


    .heading {
        margin-top: .5em;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
        width: 100%;
    }

    th,
    td,
    table {
        border: none !important;
    }

}
```

and my link looks like this

```
<link href="css/print.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" media="print">
```